# Do not pass data to OS in observer mode in Wacom Feel Multi Touch API

Tags: c#, wpf, wacom

I am currently making a little application that lets me use my Intuos Pro as a keyboard because it is touch enabled. Wacom has released [an API](http://us.wacom.com/en/developerrelations/feel-multi-touch) that allows the access of touch data so getting the core functionality has not been a problem. I have hit a bit of a snag, though. The API allows you to listen for data in two modes:

- *Consumer Mode* means that the application will not pass touch information onto any other applications or to the driver for gesture recognition. It will only listen if the window has keyboard focus.
- *Observer Mode* means that the application will pass touch information onto other applications and will always listen for data regardless of focus.

Here's my problem. The keyboard needs to be running all the time, but when I'm typing on my touchpad, I don't want two finger scrolls or tap clicking or anything to happen. But if I'm typing into something, the thing I'm typing into has to have keyboard focus - not my application.

I can't really see the point of observer mode if there's no way to destroy data so that gesture recognition doesn't get in the way. And in their [FAQ](http://www.wacomeng.com/touch/WacomFeelMulti-TouchFAQ.htm), Wacome hinted at the possibility of being able to destroy data in observer mode.

> If the application chooses to pass the touch data through to the driver in Observer mode, then the tablet driver will interpret touch data and recognize gestures as appropriate for the tablet and operating system.

So I am suspicious of there being a solution. I was wondering if anyone has had any experience with this, or would be able to take a look and see if they can figure out a solution? I'm okay with something hacky if need be as this is more of a personal thing than anything else.

I am using their MTDN variety in C# in Visual Studio 2013 and my application is currently a WPF application.

Comment: From what I understand of the [FAQ](http://www.wacomeng.com/touch/WacomFeelMulti-TouchFAQ.htm#_Toc331140775) the *Observer Mode* is not what you want, since it is promiscuous, the tablet's events are dispatched to whoever wants to listen. On the other hand *"in **Consumer mode**, the  forefront Wacom Feel™ Multi-Touch API enabled application is the only process to receive touch data.  The data is not passed on for gesture processing, to the system or other multi-touch applications."* Maybe I'm missing something but I think the mode you want is consumer.

Comment: @juan.facorro You may be correct on that one, but consumer mode the application will stop receiving touch events the instant the window is no longer in keyboard focus. I'd be happy to accept a solution that uses consumer mode and somehow tricks the API - I don't have enough knowledge of the API or desktop Windows applications to do something like that on my own though.

Comment: I want to archive a similar behavior and ended up using pinvoke to pass the keyboard messages from wndproc to the next program. But atm, I'm not able to get it working...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28288372/fiddling-with-multitouch